# Fill up all the available height of a parent box

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have this html structure:

```
#### body #######################
#                               #
#      ###### .box #######      #
#      #    .box-header  #      #
#      ###################      #  
#      #                 #      #
#      #                 #      #            
#      #    .box-body    #      #
#      #                 #      #
#      #                 #      #
#      ###################      #
#      #   .box-footer   #      #
#      ###################      # 
#                               # 
#################################
```

You can see the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B2zTM/).

For reference, **HTML**:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h1>.box-header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
        <h2>.box-body</h2>
        <p>This should fill up the available space in order to move the box-footer to the bottom.
            <br/><br/>
           If this it has been done right the red background should not be displayed.
        </p>            
    </div>
    <div class="box-footer">
        <h3>.box-footer</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the **CSS**:

```css
body{
    height: 400px;
}
.box{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: red;
}
.box-header{
    background-color: green;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.box-header h1{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.box-body{
    background-color: blue;
}

.box-body p, .box-body h2{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: white;
}

.box-footer{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: black;
}

.box-footer h3{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: white;
}
```

Is there any way to force `.box-body` to fill up all the available height of the `.box`?

Note that this is a cleaner version of my html. The real example have a fixed bar on top, footer and left. What I am trying to do is to add a second left sidebar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it with CSS tables.

Apply the following **CSS**:

```css
body{
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
}
.box{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: red;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.box-header{
    background-color: green;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: table-row;
}

.box-body{
    background-color: blue;
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}

.box-footer{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: black;
    display: table-row;
}
```

For `.box`, apply `display: table` with `width: 100%` (or else it becomes shrink-to-fit).

For `.box-header`, `.box-body`, `.box-footer`, set `display: table-row`.

To force `.box-body` to take up the maximum height, set `height: 100%`.

This works in the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/ntW6s/

The attractive feature of this solution is that you don't need to specify heights for the header and footer elements.

Note that the height computation algorithm for tables can vary among browsers so you may see some variation with older browsers that may render tables differently.

The result looks like:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it's it! :D I was trying to set height to 100% but without display table and table-row the body element was getting the total height of the parent box without discounting the other child elements (header and footer). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `height:100%` to `.box-body`:

```
.box-body{
    background-color: blue;
    height:100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/B2zTM/1/)**

Comment: In my case, the real one, it assumes the 400px of the .box without subtracting the .box-body and .box-footer height...